# Product delete option for each product as edit in admin product grid

Tags: magento-1.8, grid

I am using magento 1.8.
My requirement is to display delete option in product grid in front of each product like "Edit" option.
I have created column and able to display the Delete option in grid using following code in

```
Npm_Product_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Grid

$this->addColumn('Delete action',
            array(
                'header'    => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Action'),
                'width'     => '50px',
                'type'      => 'action',
                'getter'     => 'getId',
                'actions'   => array(
                    array(
                        'caption' => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Delete'),
                        'url'     => array(
                            'base'=>'*/*/delte',
                            'params'=>array('store'=>$this->getRequest()->getParam('store'))
                        ),
                        'field'   => 'id'
                    )
                ),
                'filter'    => false,
                'sortable'  => false,
                'index'     => 'stores',
        ));
```

When I click on delete it redirecting but showing 404 error, Any idea how can I implement this requirement?

How can I call **productController deleteAction** from here with parameter **product id** 
Thanks in advance:)

Comment: there is a spelling mistake in **url** `'base' =>'*/*/delete'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
       $this->addColumn('delete',
            array(
                'header'    => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Delete'),
                'width'     => '50px',
                'type'      => 'action',
                'getter'     => 'getId',
                'actions'   => array(
                    array(
                        'caption' => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Delete'),
                        'url'     => array(
                            'base'=>'*/*/delete',
                            'params'=>array('store'=>$this->getRequest()->getParam('store'))
                        ),
                        'field'   => 'id'
                    )
                ),
                'filter'    => false,
                'sortable'  => false,
                'index'     => 'stores',
            ));
```

Comment: if it works than please mark it as accepted

Answer (score 0):

```
    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
            $this->addColumn("videogallery_id", array(
            "header" => Mage::helper("videogallery")->__("ID"),
            "align" =>"center",
            "type" => "number",
            "index" => "videogallery_id",
            ));
            $this->addColumn("videogallery_url", array(
            "header" => Mage::helper("videogallery")->__("Video Thumbnail"),
            "index" => "videogallery_url",
            "align" =>"center",
            "width" => "200px",
            'renderer'  => 'videogallery/renderer_image',
            ));

            $this->addColumn("name", array(
            "header" => Mage::helper("videogallery")->__("Video Name"),
            "index" => "name",
            ));
            $this->addColumn('action',
            array(
                'header' => Mage::helper('videogallery')->__('Action'),
                'width' => '120',
                'type' => 'action',
                'getter' => 'getId',
                'actions'   => array(
                    array(
                        'caption'   => Mage::helper('videogallery')->__('Delete Video'),
                        'url'       => array('base'=> '*/*/delete'),
                        'field'     => 'id',
                        'confirm'  => Mage::helper('videogallery')->__('Are you sure?')
                    )
                ),
                'filter' => false,
                'sortable' => false,
                'index' => 'stores',
                'is_system' => true,
            ));
     $this->addRssList('videogallery/adminhtml_rss_rss/videogallery', Mage::helper('videogallery')->__('RSS'));
        $this->addExportType('*/*/exportCsv', Mage::helper('sales')->__('CSV')); 
        $this->addExportType('*/*/exportExcel', Mage::helper('sales')->__('Excel'));

            return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }
```